# Grails 3.0 app starts on unexpected path. How to fix?

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

I just start using Grails 3.0 RC1 and find out minor problem. After run-app command, my application available at path localhost:8080, but on Grails 2.x correct path by default was localhost:8080/appname/. In docs for Grails 3.0 I see the same, application should starts on localhost:8080/appname/. Why was /appname/ suffix lost in my case? I have very simple test application and did not tune config files. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set a grails 3 app to use a root context path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721715/how-to-set-a-grails-3-app-to-use-a-root-context-path)

Comment: @lifeisfoo does it make sense that actually question on your link is a possible duplicate of my question?:) Check the dates. And these are different questions, actually. Answer is the same, but source problems are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs of springboot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties), you would configure:

```
server.context-path= # the context path, defaults to '/'
```

E.g. add in your `application.yml`:

```
server:
    'context-path': '/lol'
```

To access your app in the context *lol*

Comment: Sorry, not clear understand, what should I set in these options to get appname suffix? What config file should I add these options?