# how to set a grails 3 app to use a root context path?

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

I'm trying to set a root context path for my application in `conf/application.yml' like so:

```
server:
    'context-path': '/'
```

However, when trying to start `grails> run-app`, I get the following exception:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have paid more attention to the error log output from `run-app`.  The correct setting is:

```
server:
    'context-path': ''
```

>= Grails 3.0.3:

```
server:
    contextPath: ''
```

Answer (score 10):

From Grails 3.0.3, the [expected configuration key is `contextPath`](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9020#issuecomment-112777220), camel case and not hyphenated. So the right setting in your `application.yml` is:

```
server:
    contextPath: '/my-path'
```

Or, if you're using `application.groovy`:

```
server.contextPath='/my-path'
```